# Shared Library on Linux is not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I have built some shared libraries on Ubuntu Linux 16.0.2 from source.

They are 64-bit libs.

I manually copied them to /usr/local/lib.

I verified that the /usr/local/lib path is indeed in one of the .conf files that ld.so.conf includes.

I then ran: sudo ldconfig to update the cache.

But then when I try to run my executable which tries to dynamically load one of the .so files that I previously copied into /usr/local/lib using dlopen, it fails.

In my code, I have:

```
dlopen ("foobar.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic linker normally doesn't access the paths recursively included from `/etc/ld.so.conf` directly, but it uses a cache.

You can update the cache with

```
sudo ldconfig
```

See [ldconfig(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) for more details.

Comment: I did that but still no luck.

Comment: When I execute sudo ldconfig-v, the libraries that I copied into /usr/local/lib do not appear in the text dump.  Don't understand why.

Comment: @rohitsan Interesting, I tried it on my system and it seems its name needs to start with `lib`. IOW, it works for me with `libfoobar.so` (assuming the permissions are correct, but not `foobar.so`).

Comment: `ldconfig` is normally run at boot, but probably the OP has not rebooted the machine.

Comment: @rohitsan, you have to define a soname for that libraries and them have to be called like the soname... normally you'll see the library complete name, and a soft link pointing to it from the soname.  Only then a library is included in the cache map.

Answer (score 0):

for `dlopen` to work, there's no directory list of places to find the shared object.  So doing `dlopen("somefile", ...);` probably won't work.

You don't need to use any path or to put the shared object (or to comply with naming conventions) to use a shared object via `dlopen(3)`.  That's only a requirement of the dynamic linker that loads and links all the shared libraries at launch time: `linux-vdso.so.1` (in 64bit)

To test, just put the shared in your local dir and try to open it with it's basename, like you post.

For a system library, there are more requirements, like defining a *soname* for the library, which is used by the loader to load the library and to construct the cache database index, so if you have no idea of what I'm talking about, you will not be able to use automatic loading procedure.  If you want to see if an executable file has all the libraries it needs and where the loader finds them out, just run `ldd(1)` with the executable as argument, and you'll se the dependencies for automatic loading and how the dynamic linker resolves the paths.